# Как изменять размер TextView в зависимости от его содержимого?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Как растягивать textview в зависимости от того сколько там текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте constraints сверху, справа и слева. Высоту оставьте динамической, отключите функцию *Scrolling Enable.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение второй ситуации.

1. Создаете `ScrollView` (растягивает по всему основному View).
2. На `ScrollView` наносите UIView (дальше по тексту contentView) и так же растягиваете по всему экрану.
3. Выставляете ширину contentView она должна быть равна ширине основного вью.
4. Раскидываете элементы в contentView. `TextView` используете так, как я описал выше. Важно чтобы была взаимосвязь всех элементов в contentView по высоте. Так как его высота будет динамическая.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как сделать так чтобы он вместе со ScrollView листался?

Comment: Опишите вопрос более детально. Не очень понятно что необходимо.

Comment: Вот смотрите, у меня есть view и текст который я ввожу в textview не помещается в этот view, я поставил scrollview и все вроде должно быть нормально, но scrollview скроллится только немного, как сделать так чтобы scrollview охватывал область всего textview?

Comment: А почему не растянуть textView на весь экран, и оставить возможность его скролить, без ScrollView?

Comment: Потому что помимо textview есть еще и другие компоненты

Comment: Поправил ответ. Если будет что-то не ясно, напишите.

Comment: Спасибо огромное